# Vue 3 – fade transition broken

Tags: javascript, fade, vuejs3

I read about the transition changes from Vue 2 however and read the Vue 3 docs but I still can't figure out how to make the transition work. **I'm very new to Vue.**

The old page should fade out and the new page should fade in, I can't get it to work though.

I don't really know what to write inside the `<transition>` wrapper other than the default *component*. I tried changing *component* to the views' names but that doesn't work.

My `App.vue`

```
<router-view :key="route.path" v-slot="{Component}" />
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

My CSS:

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

My folder structure:

```
Components: – Header.vue
  |         - Footer.vue
  |
Views:      - Home.vue
            - About.vue
            - Something.vue
```

Thanks for any tips on how to make the fade work!

Answer (score 5):

Try using `.fade-leave-to` instead:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const test = Vue.ref(false);
    
    return { test }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div v-if="test">FADE</div>
  </transition>
  <button @click="test = !test">TOGGLE</button>
</div>
```

Example using your snippet:

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <component :is="Component" />
    </transition>
</router-view>
```

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah that would be perfect, but I can't wrap the <router-view> in a <transition> per vue3

Comment: The transition still works the same when wrapped around `<component :is="component">`

Comment: Unfortunately not, it says `[Vue warn]: Property "Component" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your snippet. It works as expected for me, does it still not work for you?

Comment: I had to remove the trailing slash in the component tag to get rid of the [Vue warn] then it worked. Thx for the CSS!